# Agregar espacios antes de mayusculas

Tags: java

Tengo un String que tiene algún texto como el siguiente : 
    "soyUnaOración"

lo que quiero es poder agregar espacios antes de las mayusculas para que quede de la siguiente forma :
"soy Una Oración"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un simple regex: el cual captura dos grupos en las variables `$1`y `$2`y las separa por un espacio, `[A-Z]` le indique que capture las mayúsculas solamente.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FICBhd)**

```
class Espacio
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text="soyUnaOración";
        String sNuevo = text.replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
        System.out.println(sNuevo);

    }
}
```

---

**RESULTADO**

> `soy Una Oración`

Comment: Gracias, aunque me parece que los imports son innecesarios para esté caso

Comment: @gibranalexismorenozuñiga Es correcto. Los import me los pone ideone por defecto y nunca los quito. Pero es cierto que podría prestarse a confusión. Me alegro de que hayas resuelto  tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola pues pueden existir varias formas de lograrlo, aquí te pongo un ejemplo simple:

```
          String laCadena="unaOracionHola";
            StringBuffer nuevaCadena = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0;i<laCadena.length(); i++)
            {
               if (Character.isUpperCase(laCadena.charAt(i))) {
                  nuevaCadena.append(" ");
                  nuevaCadena.append(laCadena.toCharArray()[i]);
               } else {
                  nuevaCadena.append(laCadena.charAt(i));
               }
            }
            System.out.println(nuevaCadena);
```

Salida:
una Oracion Hola